# Regex expression validation for numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

This regex expression that I have validate the situation below:

Correct input:

1. 12345678,12345678,12345678
2. *space*12345678 , 12345678 , 12345678 , 12345678
3. 12345678,12345678,*space*
4. 12345678
5. *space*12345678,
6. 12345678,

Result: return true(regex expression is working correctly for situations above.)

wrong input:

1. 1234567812345678

Result: return true (should be false)

For wrong input it should be returning false , but it return true. what should i do to validate for the wrong input?

```
   var validate_commas = /^(\s*\d{8}\s*[,]?\s*)*$/;
```

Thank you

Comment: Maybe you should specify the grammar of your correct input instead of showing some examples.

Comment: you need to return false on that last one you mentioned?

Comment: Hi, Kimberlee - I think you should accept one of the answers as at least 2 of them work. This way people will know when they come here with the same problem what they ought to do :)

Comment: I am not sure why you accepted drquicksilver's answer. It does not even pass some of your test cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See **Ambiguity in description** for more details on why your question is ambiguous, and how that affects the answers you get.

I assume spaces (ASCII 32) are arbitrarily allowed:

- At the start of the string
- At the end of the string
- Before and after comma.

I assume that you want to **disallow** horizontal tabs, new lines, carriage returns and [other *whitespace* characters matched by `\s`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), and only allow space (ASCII 32) to be freely specified.

The BNF grammar with the above assumptions is:

```
<DIGIT>  ::= "0" | "1" | "2" | "3" | "4" | "5" | "6" | "7" | "8" | "9"
<NUMBER> ::= <DIGIT> {8}
<SPACE>  ::= " "
<TOKEN>  ::= <SPACE>* <NUMBER> <SPACE>*
<LIST>   ::= <TOKEN> ( "," <TOKEN> )* [ "," <SPACE>* ]
```

With the grammar above, it is easy to write the regex solution:

```
var regex = /^ *\d{8} *(?:, *\d{8} *)*(?:, *)?$/;
```

#### Ambiguity in description

Rather than showing examples of what string you want to match, as suggested, your should specify a grammar for your input. Examples may not cover all the cases, and the answerer usually assumes "don't care" or make up some assumptions for the cases not stated in the examples.

Comment: Hi, Thank you. I have edited the expression to take 12345678*space* as true.

What i got is this: ^\s*\d{8}\s*(\s*,\s*(?:\d{8})?)*$

Comment: @Kimberlee: Please use the solution `/^ *\d{8} *(?:, *\d{8} *)*(?:, *)?$/` The other one is just a counter-example, which shows that it matches more than what you may want. (I have removed it to make my post unambiguous).

Answer (score 0):

Does removing the optional comma help?

```
var validate_commas = /^(\s*\d{8}\s*)(,\s*\d{8}\s*)*,?$/;
```

Without clearer information, this is the best that can be done without making more assumptions...
e.g. will there ever only be one numbers and no commas?

Comment: yeap. there will be one set of numbers without commas.

Comment: Try this maybe? --- var validate_commas = /^(\s*\d{8}[^\d]\s*,?\s*)*$/;

Comment: Hi, its not working for 12345678 without comma. 12345678 should return true.

Comment: So what should it return 'false' for exactly?

Comment: Also, in that case, the regex in the answer does not work for your purposes? if not, please say, precisely, where it doesn't work...

Comment: Hi, I've edited my questions again. ^(\s*\d{8}[^\d]\s*,?\s*)*$ is unable to return true for 12345678,12345678.

Comment: let's remove the anchors - I think it should work:  /(\s*\d{8}[^\d]\s*,?\s*)*/  (maybe g)

Comment: Ok, now I got it. Sorry for the stuff around. /^(\s*\d{8},?)*$/ should work

Comment: Hi, i think i got it already. hmm.. this is the regex expression: ^(\s*\d{8}\s*,*\s*)(,\s*\d{8}\s*,*\s*)*$

Comment: And I haven't slept in days and I neglected the spaces...      /^(\s*\d{8}\s*,?\s*)*$/     - just try that.

Comment: Yep - but you won't need to repeat like that in my opinion. See if the latter option here is equivalent to your solution maybe?

Comment: erm.. String tested: 1234567812345678,12345678 result still true. hmm

Comment: OK, I finally got it:   /^(\s*\d{8}\s*)(,\s*\d{8}\s*)*$/

Comment: @d'alar'cop kinda feeling sorry for you struggling that much while failing to notice drquicksilver already posted this :/

Comment: hahaha... well I came to it independently... swear to God. -- well it's in both answers now. I'll leave it to you where you hit that tick button!

Comment: Trailing comma case is not covered.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
var validate_commas = /^(\s*\d{8}\s*(?:$|,\s*))*$/;
```

It will take one or more instances of 8 numeric characters followed by the end of the string or another comma.

Or alternatively if you do not want the expression to match an empty line, change the last quantifier to the one or more character: +

```
var validate_commas = /^(\s*\d{8}\s*(?:$|,\s*))+$/;
```

Will return **true** on the following inputs:

```
12345678,12345678,12345678
*space*12345678 , 12345678 , 12345678 , 12345678
12345678,12345678,*space*
12345678
*space*12345678,
12345678,
```

Will return **false** on the following inputs:

```
1234567812345678
sdsdsfsd
12345678, 12345678 12345678
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Although you claim that it returns true on `12345678,12345678,*space*`, it actually return false.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
var validate_commas = /^\s*\d{8}(\s*,\s*(?:\d{8})?)*$/;
```

Much like the other suggestions, except it makes the additional numbers optional, thus allowing for `12345678,` etc.

Comment: Yours will allow `23442344,,` to pass

Answer (score -1):

You mean the comma is not optional between numbers?

Try this:

```
var validate_commas = /^(\s*\d{8}\s*)(,\s*\d{8}\s*)*$/;
```

Incidentally this doesn't accept the empty string which your example did. Not sure if you really wanted that.

Comment: Trailing comma case is not covered.